# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable and 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I am trying to concatenate the layers from my model, but getting an error and I checked the solution for the error at StackOverflow, but couldn't implement in my code.

I tried to implement `tf.concat()` and `keras.layers.Concatenate`, but for them also I got an error like `NoneType` object has no attribute `_inbound_nodes`.

```
# Define the model

def my_model(input_shape, output):

  if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'tf':
            input_shape= (input_shape[1], input_shape[2], input_shape[0])

  input = Input(input_shape)


  conv_1 = bn_conv(32, (3,3), 1, padding="same")(input)   #RF-3
 #conv_2 = bn_conv(48, (3,3), 1, padding="same")(conv_1)  #RF-5
 #conv_3 = bn_conv(64, (3,3), 1, border_mode="same")(conv_2)  #RF-7

  conv_4 = bn_conv(32, (1,3), 1, padding = "same")(conv_1)
  conv_5 = bn_conv(64,(3,1), 1, padding = "same")(conv_4) #RF-7  

  skip1 = space_to_depth_x2(conv_5)



  conv_6 = keras.layers.SeparableConv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3,3), 
           strides= 1, padding = "same")(conv_5)
  conv_7 = bn_conv(128, (1,1), 1, padding = "same")(conv_6) # RF-9

  skip2 = space_to_depth_x2(conv_7)



  max_1 = MaxPooling2D((2,2),2)(conv_7) #RF-18, size - 16
  conv_8 = bn_conv(128, (1,1), 1)(max_1)

  #skip3 = space_to_depth_x3(conv_8)



  #E_merge = merge([skip1, skip2, conv_8], mode = "concat", concat_axis =-1)
   E_merge = concatenate([skip1, skip2, conv_8], axis=-1)



   conv_g1 = bn_conv(32, (1,1),1, padding="same")(E_merge)
   conv_g2 = bn_conv(64, (3,3),1, padding = "same")(conv_g1)# RF - 20

   conv_g3 = bn_conv(32, (1,1), 1, padding = "same")(E_merge)
   conv_g4 = bn_conv(64, (5,5), 1, padding = "same")(conv_g3)# RF - 22

   max_g1 = AveragePooling2D((2,2),strides=(1,1), padding="same")(E_merge) 

   conv_g5 = Conv2D(64, (1,1))(max_g1)

   conv_9 = Conv2D(64,(1,1))(E_merge) #RF - 18



   #merge_1 = merge([conv_g2, conv_g4, conv_g5, conv_9], mode = "concat", 
              concat_axis =-1)# RF - 18, 22, 20, 36
   merge_1 = Concatenate(axis=-1)([conv_g2, conv_g4, conv_g5, conv_9])

   conv_g6 = bn_conv(32, (1,1), 1, padding = "same")(merge_1)
   conv_g7 = bn_conv(64, (3,3), 1, padding = "same", dilation_rate = (1,1)) 
             (conv_g6)

   conv_g8 = bn_conv(32, (1,1), 1, padding = "same")(merge_1)
   conv_g9 = bn_conv(128, (3,3),1,  padding = "same", dilation_rate =(2,2)) 
             (conv_g8)

    #max_g2 = MaxpPooling2D(2,2, border_mode="same")(merge_1)
    conv_g10 = Conv2D(64, (1,1), padding ="same")(merge_1)  


    #merge_2 = merge([conv_g7, conv_g9, conv_g10], mode = "concat", 
                 concat_axis =-1) 
    merge_2 = Concatenate(axis=-1)([conv_g7, conv_g9, conv_g10])

    #conv_9 = bn_conv(64, (3,3), 1, border_mode = "valid")(merge_2)  

    #conv_10 = bn_conv(128, (3,3), 1, border_mode = "valid")(conv_9)

    conv_11 = Conv2D(32, (1,1))(merge_2)

    conv_12 = Conv2D(10,(16,16))(conv_11)

    flat = Flatten() (conv_12)

    act = Activation("softmax")(flat)

    model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=act)

    return model

model = my_model([3, 32, 32], 10)
```

For Concatenate getting following error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-6acaac7e556d> in <module>()
     97   return model
     98 
---> 99 model = my_model([3, 32, 32], 10)
    100 from keras.optimizers import Adam
    101 

24 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1323             ValueError: if a cycle is detected.
   1324         """
-> 1325         node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
   1326 
   1327         # Prevent cycles.

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `merge` module was removed from keras some time ago, you have two options:

- The concatenate functional API:

  ```
  from keras.layers import concatenate

  E_merge = concatenate([skip1, skip2, conv_8], axis=-1)
  ```
- The Concatenate layer:

  ```
  from keras.layers import Concatenate

  E_merge = Concatenate(axis=-1)([skip1, skip2, conv_8])
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I tried both and got this error for both.
    "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

Comment: Please suggest me some solution or some links to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: @KiranKumarG Update your question will full code and traceback

Comment: If you don't mind, kindly share your email id,  I will share my colab file with you for better analysis.

Comment: @KiranKumarG No, that's not how Stack Overflow works, you have to include details in your question.

Comment: @ Matias Valdenegro, I have updated, please check now.

Comment: @KiranKumarG The error seems to be unrelated to my answer, your code is not complete, make a self-contained example that reproduces the problem.